# C # submit form with sql database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a registration form i would like to submit to a SQL 2008 database, I thought I had it right, but it doesn't seem to be working.  i posted the code belowe to show what i have so far.

Basically I would like to know if the code i have should work, if not could someone show me how to tweek what i have.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection NutRegistration = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server; Initial Catalog=DBname;Integrated Security=false;User ID=uname;Password=password");
    NutRegistration.Open();

    SqlCommand thisCommand = NutRegistration.CreateCommand();
    thisCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (txtNickName, txtEmail, txtPassword) VALUES (nickname, email, password);";

    NutRegistration.Close();
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not executing the Command, you are just setting the CommandText.
This should work:

```
thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Do it after setting CommandText and before closing the connection.
This will also return the number of affected rows.

Comment: i was infact missing this, but also the open and close commands should of been within a try catch statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will happen. You are not executing the command, only creating it. You must do this to actually submit it to the database.

```
thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```